# How can I reverse the string and parse it with '-' in Java

Tags: java

I have to reverse the given string and parse it with "-".
For example.

INPUT: **abcde**
OUTPUT : **e-d-c-b-a**

Any simple solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `StringBuilder#reverse`

Using [`StringBuilder#reverse`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse()) we can try:

```java
String input = "abcde";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input);
String output = sb.reverse().toString().replaceAll("(?<=.)(?=.)", "-");
System.out.println(output);  // e-d-c-b-a
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/2At8VL).

For an explanation on the regex pattern used in [`String#replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) above, it aims to match every position in the string where there are letters on both side:

```regex
(?<=.)  assert that some character precedes
(?=.)   assert that some character follows
```

Comment: Thank you, but can you please elaborate on the "(?<=.)(?=.)" and its use case here?

Comment: Check the updated answer for an explanation about the regex used.

Comment: You could also do `String output = String.join("-", sb.reverse().toString().split(""));`

Answer (score 2):

Iterate the `String` in reverse. Join the output with `-`. Like,

```
String s = "abcde";
System.out.println(IntStream.range(0, s.length())
        .mapToObj(i -> String.valueOf(s.charAt(s.length() - i - 1)))
        .collect(Collectors.joining("-")));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
         String letters = "abcde";
          (int i = letters.length()-1; i >= 0; i--){
               char c = letters.charAt(i);
               System.out.print(c + "-");
           }
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Also, your code is a syntax error as it's missing `for`.

Comment: Even if this was correct, this just prints to the screen once, meaning if you want to do it again, you have to run the loop again.